# Font color changes to gray instead of Black in React Native Release APK

Tags: react-native

I'm having a weird problem with my app. The app font color is perfectly fine in the debug version but when I build a release version APK, the font color changes to gray

[Release version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KevRV.jpg)

[Debug version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zfzR.jpg)